# How determine contact point in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Is there a way to determine the contact point x,y values for the two physics bodies that collide?

I'm trying to determine whether the contact on one of the bodies is on the top, bottom,left or right side.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually the answer below does not give me what I want.  It returns the screen coordinate of the point of contact.  What I'm looking for is the coordinate on the object where contact, that is which part of the object made the contact.  I could probably use SKPhysicsContact.contactPoint and do some math to calculate what I need, I'm just asking if there's something build in that I need.

Comment: Of course that you have to do some math (if you don't have a node with four physics bodies). But the point is that you should use contactPoint property. Or, you could probably go with just positions of nodes which are in contact. You can try by yourself, and if you are still stuck, you can update your question with the code which can reproduce the issue. Don't get me wrong, but that way, you will likely get  your answer sooner (instead of waiting for somebody who will write a whole solution for you). That is how SO works.

Comment: I wasn't asking for someone to write a solution, I was asking if the kit had something built in.  Don't need nor appreciate the lecture on how SO works

Answer (score 2):

Classes that conform to `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol may implement two methods called `didBeginContact` and `didEndContact`. Those methods accept `SKPhysicsContact` object.

From the docs:

> An SKPhysicsContact object is created automatically by Sprite Kit to
>   describe a contact between two physical bodies in a physics world.

So if you observe this object (a parameter called `contact`) you will notice that it has a property called [contactPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsContact/contactPoint).

That is what you are looking for.